# Creating ModelAdmin that has more then 1 view

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm currently working on a project that has a more of a complex Admin page.

Currently what I'm trying to accomplish is when a user adds a Report this report then checks a bunch of data and create a list of people within the area (Less then 10 km).  So when they add a report when you click save its changes view to a view that lists all the people it found and their emails, you can then select the people you want to add and press another button which does more stuff.

My code is as follows:

```
admin.register(Report)
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/phone/index.html'
    # inlines = [SubjectInLine]
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        """
        Determines the HttpResponse for the change_view stage.
        """
        opts = self.model._meta
        msg_dict = {'name': force_text(opts.verbose_name), 'obj': force_text(obj)}
        context = {}

        if "_email" in request.POST:
            msg = _('Report Saved - Now please select the store below you would like to notify.') % msg_dict
            self.message_user(request, msg, messages.SUCCESS)
            payload = {'address': str(obj.location.address1) + ' ' + str(obj.location.address2)}
            start = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", params=payload)
            start = start.json()
            start_long = start['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
            start_lat = start['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            start_loc = (float(start_lat), float(start_long))
            clients = Clients.objects.filter()
            context['report'] = obj

            in_ten = []
            for c in clients:
                payload = {'address': str(c.address1) + ' ' + str(c.address2)}
                end = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", params=payload)
                try:
                    end = end.json()
                    end_long = end['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
                    end_lat = end['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
                    end_loc = (float(end_lat), float(end_long))
                    distance = vincenty(start_loc, end_loc).kilometers
                    if (distance < 10 and c.pk != obj.location.pk):
                        in_ten.append(c)
                except:
                    print(str(c) + " Bad Address")

            context["clients"] = in_ten
            obj.save()
            return render(request,'phone/email.html',context)

        elif "_confirm-email" in request.POST:
            print ("HELLO")
            print (context["report"])
            return render(request, 'phone/email.html', context)
        else:
            msg = _('The %(name)s "%(obj)s" was changed successfully.') % msg_dict
            self.message_user(request, msg, messages.SUCCESS)
            return self.response_post_save_change(request, obj)


    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(ReportAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

Code of phone/email.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_static admin_modify %}

{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
{{ media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-form{% endblock %}


{% block content %}<div id="content-main">
<form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
<h1>Email Section</h1>
    <div style="height:500px">
         <table>
             <th>Location</th>
             <th>Email</th>
             <th>Include in Email?</th>
             {% for c in clients %}
             <tr>
                 <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ c.contact_email }}</td>
                 <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{c.name}}"></td>
             </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </table>
        <div class="submit-row">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Email Confirmation' %}" class="default" name="_email-confirm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form></div>
{% endblock %}
```

So you can see that I override the response_change method and then when i notice the _email button was press I render a new page.   Now this does work. Now when this new template is rendered, and I press the _email-confirm button it just reloads the page from the beginning and no print statements are seen.

Any insight will be great.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured a way around this:

I was working with the wrong method provided by Django.

The way I did this was by:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    context = {}
    if "_email-confirm" in request.POST:
        print ("CONFIRM")
        return render(request,'phone/confirm.html',context)
    if "_continue" in request.POST:
        print ("CONTINUE")
        '''
        obj = Report.objects.get(pk=object_id)
        payload = {'address': str(obj.location.address1) + ' ' + str(obj.location.address2)}
        start = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", params=payload)
        start = start.json()
        start_long = start['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        start_lat = start['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        start_loc = (float(start_lat), float(start_long))
        clients = Clients.objects.filter()
        context['report'] = obj
        in_ten = []
        for c in clients:
            payload = {'address': str(c.address1) + ' ' + str(c.address2)}
            end = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", params=payload)
            try:
                end = end.json()
                end_long = end['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
                end_lat = end['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
                end_loc = (float(end_lat), float(end_long))
                distance = vincenty(start_loc, end_loc).kilometers
                if (distance < 10 and c.pk != obj.location.pk):
                    in_ten.append(c)
                    print (c.address)
            except:
                print(str(c) + " Bad Address")

        context["clients"] = in_ten
        '''
        return render(request,'phone/email.html',context)
        #return super(ReportAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, 'phone/email.html', context)
    else:
        return super(ReportAdmin, self).change_view(request,object_id,form_url)
```

So here what I did was intercept the change_view and made sure to render the page I wanted.

Hope this helps others.